# bind 9.11 with views and also-notify with keys: slaves receive notifications with wrong keys

Tags: bind, key

Example error message from a slave shows notification for view avcan received with key vpn

```
May 21 06:37:09 dns5.iciti named[614]: client @0x7f3f0c8472b0 192.168.8.54#49401/key vpn: view avcan: received notify for zone '8.16.172.in-addr.arpa': TSIG 'vpn': not authoritative
```

named.conf.options has

```
notify explicit;
```

named.conf.local has

```
acl vpn {
    !key avcan;
    key vpn;
    172.16.0.0/12;
};
acl avcan { 
    !key vpn;
    key avcan;
    10.10.0.0/16;
    ...
};

key "avcan" {
    algorithm HMAC-SHA512;
    secret "<redacted>";
};
key "vpn" {
    algorithm HMAC-SHA512;
    secret "<redacted>";
}

...

view avcan {
    match-clients { avcan; };
    also-notify {
        192.168.8.55 key avcan;
        ...
    };
--
view vpn {
    match-clients { vpn; };
    also-notify {
        192.168.8.55 key vpn;
        ...
    };
```

If I understand how also-notify works, the master should send notifications for view avcan with key avcan but the error messages from the slaves show it is also sending notifications with key vpn

Answer (score 0):

My bad.  The master had acl stanzas as shown above.  The slaves were missing the !key lines.  Sorry for the noise.  Maybe it helps somebody.